# How to filter search query on appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is it possible not just sort results of query(com.google.appengine.api.search.Query), but also filter them? Like for example in this query com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query:

```
Filter heightMinFilter =
new FilterPredicate("height",
                  FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                  minHeight);
Query q = new Query("Person").setFilter(heightMinFilter);
```

Search query has options that are needed for sorting, but I also want to filter result, because there are too many of them and I need only specific.

Comment: But you can filter results using the `setFilter()` method. Why don't you do that?

Comment: setFilter() available only in datastore.Query, but is absent in search.Query. Those are different objects.

Comment: Oops, I see. My mistake.

Comment: Have you read [this page on query strings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings)? It gives examples on field-restricted queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter is part of the query string.

> A query string specifies conditions for the values of one or more
>   document fields. When you search an index you get back only those
>   documents in the index with fields that satisfy the query.

See example below or find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings).

```
String queryString = "product: piano AND price < 5000";

Query query = Query.newBuilder().build(queryString);

Results<ScoredDocument> results = getIndex().search(queryString);
```